# Adding third party dependancy in swift package manager issues

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I have created swift package manager. In that i have to add third party package
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts. I have added that package as dependancy in Package.swift file. It has been added and showing under package dependancies. But when i try to use that package, it is giving me error No such module 'DGCharts'. What could be the issue here?

Package file

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

    import PackageDescription
    
    let package = Package(
        name: "XYZFramework",
        platforms: [
            .iOS(.v15)
        ],
    
        
        products: [
            // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
            .library(
                name: "XYZFramework",
                targets: ["XYZFramework"]),
        ],
        dependencies: [
            // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
            // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
            .package(url: "https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "5.0.0"))
        ],
        targets: [
            // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
            // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
            .target(
                name: "XYZFramework",
                dependencies: []
                /*,
                resources: [Resource.process("XYZFramework/Sources/XYZFramework/Resources/XYZFramework.xcassets")]*/),
            .testTarget(
                name: "XYZFrameworkTests",
                dependencies: ["XYZFramework"]),
        ]
    )
```

```
import SwiftUI
import DGCharts

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    let chartView = PieChartView()

    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView()
}
```

In above  it is giving  error No such module 'DGCharts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the packaged dependency in the target's dependencies list before you can use it.

```
.target(
    name: "XYZFramework",
    dependencies: [
        .product(name: "DGCharts", package: "Charts")
    ]
)
```

> Sometimes, Xcode will ask you to explicitly declare the target's dependencies. You can help Xcode do this by using [product(name: String, package: String? = nil)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/target/dependency/product(name:package:)-fp0j)

[image: Documentation]

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/package

Comment: Hard part is to find out the correct name for the package parameter in "product(name: String, package: String? = nil)". Sometimes it is a given in the readme file, and sometimes is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I think the easiest way to identify the products produced by a package is to check the Package.swift file. Usually, they will be listed in the 'products' section. Like the DGCharts here. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Package.swift

For the package name I think you can use the name of that package's repository like "Charts" from https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git